# What's the impact of having a partition column different from the column used for HASH distribution in Azure Synapse?

Tags: database, azure, partitioning, azure-synapse

Our team is trying to convert our `Round Robin` tables in Azure Synapse to `Hash` tables due to performance reasons. But all our current `Round Robin` columns are partitioned based on a datetime field, say, `loaddate.`

But when it comes to `Hash` distribution, we'll be using a different column for each of these tables depending on the data usage, ofcourse.

Before doing this, I want to understand if there will be any impacts of partitioning the tables on a particular standard field existing in all the tables, while the HASH distribution itself happens on a different column for each of those tables.

Can you please help me with some insights in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Round Robin** : A round-robin distributed table distributes table rows evenly across all distributions. The assignment of rows to distributions is random.

**Hash** : A hash-distributed table distributes table rows across the Compute nodes by using a deterministic hash function to assign each row to one distribution.

To explain my point of view here an example :

table sales:

| load Date | Item | qte |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 04/07/2022 | 1 | 1 |
| 04/07/2022 | 1 | 2 |
| 04/07/2022 | 1 | 3 |
| 04/07/2022 | 1 | 2 |
| 04/07/2022 | 1 | 3 |
| 04/07/2022 | 2 | 1 |
| 04/07/2022 | 2 | 2 |
| 04/07/2022 | 2 | 3 |
| 04/07/2022 | 2 | 2 |
| 04/07/2022 | 2 | 3 |

**case 1 : partitioning the tables on a particular standard field existing in all the tables.** for example if we partition the data using the `loaddate` in 2 partition we can have a result like this :

parition 1 :

| load Date | Item | qte |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 04/07/2022 | 1 | 2 |
| 04/07/2022 | 1 | 3 |
| 04/07/2022 | 2 | 2 |
| 04/07/2022 | 2 | 3 |
| 04/07/2022 | 2 | 3 |

partition 2 :

| load Date | Item | qte |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 04/07/2022 | 1 | 1 |
| 04/07/2022 | 1 | 2 |
| 04/07/2022 | 1 | 3 |
| 04/07/2022 | 2 | 1 |
| 04/07/2022 | 2 | 2 |

So in this case if we want to `select Item, sum(qte) group by Item` none of the parition will have one Item data and there will be a lot of throughput and data transfer to get the result so here it's best to partition with the Item

**case 2 : HASH distribution happens on a different column for each of those tables.**

for the example table we can partition with the column Item and we will get two partitions like below:

partition 1 :

| load Date | Item | qte |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 04/07/2022 | 1 | 1 |
| 04/07/2022 | 1 | 2 |
| 04/07/2022 | 1 | 3 |
| 04/07/2022 | 1 | 2 |
| 04/07/2022 | 1 | 3 |

parition 2 :

| load Date | Item | qte |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 04/07/2022 | 2 | 1 |
| 04/07/2022 | 2 | 2 |
| 04/07/2022 | 2 | 3 |
| 04/07/2022 | 2 | 2 |
| 04/07/2022 | 2 | 3 |

and in this case we can execute the query directly `select Item, sum(qte) group by Item` and it will more optimised.

**So it's better to use the column parition depending on the sql request that you will perform.**

**Remarque :** In case of a datawarehouse it preferable to use `Replication` as distribution for the Dimensions tables this will enhance the joins operations